# I accidentally cleared the Username and Password in Halogy Admin

Tags: codeigniter, halogy

Is there anyone using Halogy codeigniter? I cannot log in to the admin right now because I accidentally cleared the Username and Password blank in Halogy Users Admin when I was updating the name. Please help me.

Comment: just create one another user with username and password and update the role of that user

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested, Halogy has moved and is now known as ForgeIgniter.

https://github.com/Forgeigniter

Or

open up the database, navigate to users and change any users groupID to -1
make sure active = 1
everything else can = null

If you're not sure for a default password, here's the default one.

```
f35364bc808b079853de5a1e343e7159
```

Comment: that is the encoded password (as is set on the database), but what is typed on the login screen once that code is set in the database?

Comment: The default username is superuser and the default password is super123.